# How should I set up a power user role for a Snowflake database?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Fundamentally I want

1. my "DBA" user; the original account which has the SYSADMIN and ACCOUNTADMIN roles, to be able to see any object in the database as well as its data.  It seems that at least at the level of ACCOUNTADMIN I should be able to do this.
2. a "power" user; via a role (dr_uce_role) I can assign at a database level where the user can do virtually everything within a database.

I thought I had made the power user role with the following code:

```sql
--grant power to engineer
grant all privileges on database dr_ev to dr_uce_role;
grant all privileges on all schemas in database dr_ev to dr_uce_role;
grant all privileges on all tables in schema dr_ev.public to dr_uce_role;
grant all privileges on all views in schema dr_ev.public to dr_uce_role;
grant select on future tables in schema dr_ev.public to dr_uce_role;
grant select on future views in schema dr_ev.public to dr_uce_role;
grant all privileges on all tables in schema dr_ev.stg to dr_uce_role;
grant all privileges on all views in schema dr_ev.stg to dr_uce_role;
grant select on future tables in schema dr_ev.stg to dr_uce_role;
grant select on future views in schema dr_ev.stg to dr_uce_role;
```

This user then created objects in the schemas.  However my "DBA" user at SYSADMIN could not see the objects at all.  With role ACCOUNTADMIN the user can see the objects, but not query them.  My understanding is that ACCOUNTADMIN is the top level account, and can take ownership of these objects anyway, so if this is supposed to be a security feature I don't really understand how it is providing much protection as it can always steal ownership?

I tried changing ownership of an object as ACCOUNTADMIN to SYSADMIN, to find it had a blocking privilege;

```sql
grant ownership on dr_ev.stg.load_opportunity to sysadmin;
```

> SQL execution error: Dependent grant of privilege 'DELETE' on securable 'DR_EV.STG.LOAD_OPPORTUNITY' to role 'DR_UCE_ROLE' exists. It must be revoked first. More than one dependent grant may exist: use 'SHOW GRANTS' command to view them. To revoke all dependent grants while transferring object ownership, use convenience command 'GRANT OWNERSHIP ON  TO  REVOKE CURRENT GRANTS'.`

I tried taking ownership with

```sql
grant ownership on all tables in schema dr_ev.stg to sysadmin revoke current grants;
```

which did work - although it left my power user unable to see the objects.  So I granted them back with

```sql
grant all privileges on all tables in schema dr_ev.stg to dr_uce_role;
```

However I want my power user to be able to create or replace this table.  I believe this requires the DROP TABLE privilege, although apparently my power user grants do not provide it, and I am unclear on how I should be providing it?

I will not say I have the greatest understanding of Snowflake privileges and am wondering if the statements above like `grant all privileges on all tables in schema` do not live at the schema level to blanket apply to all tables, but actually sets object level permissions and my original approach has simply been too granular as I do not actually wish to manage anything at object level.  That being said, I am unclear in the doc how to manage at a higher level than object anyway if the statement is actually just a shortcut to set many object privileges.  How can I accomplish my original goals?

Answer (score 1):

The best practice for a situation like this is to grant all of your custom roles to the SYSADMIN role.  This allows the sysadmin to do everything a SYSADMIN can do plus everything that all of the other roles can do.  You have a lot of questions in your post, but I think this resolves many of them.

Comment: Thanks - that actually sounds like a pretty simple good solution that would definitely resolve #1.  Is that a typical approach on Snowflake?  It does indeed sound like a best practice.

I wonder if I'd have the same problem with ownership as in my original post if I tried to make 2 db "power" groups and one made an object while the other tried to delete it; although I suppose the proper structure of that hierarchy then might be to create the privileged power role then grant that role to groupA and groupB.

Comment: The latter comment would be needed as only an owner role may delete an object. Ideally, I'd recommend having a single role control your DDL, and then other roles manipulate, load, etc. the data.  Sometimes that isn't feasible, but that is your ideal state.  If you need 2 different roles to control that, then you can grant each of them to each other.  At that point, though, you might as well only have a single role.  The Snowflake RBAC allows for a lot of flexibility in your design, but you have to think it through carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did was to create a super role 'superole' and granted sysadmin, securityadmin and accountadmin to that role. I then attached the superrole to whoever I wanted to be my DBA...

Comment: ah.  this sounds like a nice approach to create a truly top dog admin account and not have to change one's own role ever to see things.